# KNP Paginator and sortable with ajax

Tags: ajax, knppaginator

Is it possible to simply run the knp paginator with ajax? Is it possible at all and what is the best way to do it ?

Greetings Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is best solution, but I did it this way:

```
$(function(){ $('#dish-select-component-canvas').on('click', "ul.pagination a" , function(e){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        $('#dish-select-component-items').html(msg);
    });
e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

`#dish-select-component-canvas` is container for page. When somebody click on this canvas on link in `ul.pagination` (pagination is class used by `knpPaginator` by default as wrapper for pagination), I take href attribute of that link, and send it with ajax `GET` request.
Result of that request goes to appropriate div (here to `#dish-select-component-items`). Of course you must remember to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent browser from reloading the page.